# Unable to get international number with intl-tel-input and webform

Tags: webforms, drupal-8, intl-tel-input

I got massive headache getting an international number input with intl-tel-input and webform

I got the documentation here : https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input

Mentioning that I can get a international number using the "separateDialCode".

> separateDialCode
>   Type: Boolean Default: false
>   Display the country dial code next to the selected flag so it's not part of the typed number. Note that this will disable nationalMode because technically we are dealing with international numbers, but with the dial code separated.

However only a national number is posted.

Here my code included into CSS / JavaScript configuration of my webform.

```
Drupal.webform = Drupal.webform || {};
Drupal.webform.intlTelInput = Drupal.webform.intlTelInput || {};
Drupal.webform.intlTelInput.options = {
  preferredCountries: ['fr'],
  separateDialCode: true,
  autoPlaceholder: "aggressive",
  formatOnDisplay: true,
};
```

I got the separate code showing, validation working, but no international code store inside the input of my form.

I did try the hiddeninput but I do not inderstand the logic to store the full number in an hiddenInput option, if it's already managed by the librairie :(. Same with forcing nationalMode:False.

[On this picture the only result I get is "782828282", and not "+33782828282"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OKlS.png)

Anyone ?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

I have used in following format, example is based on what i am doing

```
<div class="row">
 <asp:Label ID="lblPhone" CssClass="lbl" runat="server" Text="Telephone *">
 </asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" CssClass="rg-txt rg-phone-txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtCountryCode" style="display:none;" Text="" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvPhone" ErrorMessage="*" CssClass="validate v-phone-txt" ClientValidationFunction="ValidatePhone" ValidationGroup="vg" runat="server" />
</div>



    $("#MainContent_txtPhone").intlTelInput({
        preferredCountries: ['us'],
        utilsScript: "../../Scripts/libphonenumber/utils.js"

    });

    setTimeout(function () {
         $("#MainContent_cvPhone").appendTo(".intl-tel-input");
    }, 5000);
```

during form validation i assign value of country to `txtCountryCode` `$("#MainContent_txtCountryCode").val(country);`

From code behind i get both country code & phone number on frontend  i only show `Country Flag + Phone number`.

hope this helps, I had issue running this script as i am using Master Page and script if not place in right place doesn't work properly. if you are not using Master Page approach then it should not be that much of an issue.

I dont remember if i had similar issue as you are facing as i didnt this job almost 2 years back